# NameError: name 'core' is not defined

Tags: tensorflow

I'm following the turtorial https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows, But when I try to import tensorflow, it comes with an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in  
>       import tensorflow as tf
>     File "D:\Python 3.5.3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 51, in 
>    del core
>   NameError: name 'core' is not defined

The tensorflow installation command is

> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

The full code is here
>

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')    
sess = tf.Session()                   
print(sess.run(hello))
```

The python version is 3.5.3 by the way

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your command to install TensorFlow?

Comment: I'm following the tutorial posted by Tensorflow official website, the link is here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows. The command I used is : pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

Comment: Can you post complete code?

Comment: I'm just validating the installation following the 'Validate your installation' part in this website, https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows. The full code is here:
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
It copied from the link posted above.

Comment: I find TensorFlow only working with Python 3.5.x. Not working in Python 3.6. Are you certain install TensorFlow success?

Comment: Please test again with Python 3.5.x. I think it's problem. I tested in my computer (Ubuntu 16.04). It's working because TensorFlow support Python 3.6 only in Linux and MacOS.

Comment: Yep, I'm using the version 3.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by **unticking** the option 'Precompile standard library' while installing Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall tensorflow

pip install tensorflow
```

---

solved the issue for me