# Tensorflow NameError: name 'core' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to import the KerasClassifier class with

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
```

and I get the error below

```
File "D:\Install\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    del core
NameError: name 'core' is not defined
```

I am using Windows7, Python 3.6 and Tensorflow 1.3.0

The answer of the following link didn't answer my problem [NameError: name 'core' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826680/nameerror-name-core-is-not-defined)

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue but after reinstalling the Keras it got resolved